# MsProject web app Rest API (post-Path Method)

Tags: rest, odata, project

I'm trying to make an REST API call (via postman for the moment, later it will be from an ERP) allowing me to create or modify MSProject (web app).
Oauth2.0 authentication Managed by an Azure app registration.

Endpoint: `https://<my domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/projectserver/`

Error Message:

[image: Call not OK]

Note, the same call in read mode (projectdata) works correctly.
https://.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/projectdata/

[image: Call OK]

The registration app seems to have the necessary permissions.
Any idea how to solve the problem?

Create or modify Project using the rest API.